# Separar una cantidad especifica de caracteres de una cadena en Python

Tags: python

tengo un problema, saben como separar caracteres de una cadena en N caracteres? por ejemplo: Supongamos que N=3 entonces busco que la cadena "AABCAAADA" sea separada en 3 caracteres="AAB","CAA","ADA"

primero intente separalos con split():

```
string="AABCAAADA"
split1=string.split(",",3)
print(split1)
```

pero me da como resultado: ['AABCAAADA']

luego intente con el bucle for:

```
string="AABCAAADA"
list1=[]
n=3
for i in range(0,n):
    a=list1.append(string[0:n])
print(list1)
```

pero tengo como resultado=['AAB', 'AAB', 'AAB']

Alguna ayuda o recomendación seria genial, Gracias.

Comment: `lista = [string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]`

Comment: Muchas gracias, logre resolver ese problema.